# Dynamic table headers in html

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, jstl

I need to display the headers inside  tag based upon a condition.

```
<th class="header"><h:outputText value="#{supplierScorecard.treeItemList[1].m1.header}" /> </th>
```

This is my current code. The requirement is like I need to display the particular header only if the value is present by some kind of JavaScript validation.

Note: I am not using JSF datatable here as the table header is separately printed.

Comment: You want to hide the content of header or the complete tag `<th>` ?

Comment: Be more specific and stick to the use case backed up by your code sample. There are many ways to do what you want in a broad sense.

Comment: @dShringi : Yes I want to hide the whole <TD> if condition is not satisfied

Comment: Try wraping `<th>` inside `<h:panelGroup>` and use `rendered` attribute to hide or render the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive put the  tags inside a4j:outputpanel with rendered condition and worked fine.

```
<a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{supplierScorecard.treeItemList[1].m4.header ne null}">
                                                <th class="header  treeTableOthers fixed"><h:outputText value="#{supplierScorecard.treeItemList[1].m4.header}" /> </th>
                                                </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Thanks for the update #erencan

Comment: In future questions, please explicitly mention that you're using RichFaces. It may have a solution when standard JSF haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Put your  tags inside outputPanel then give the condition to render attribute of outputPanel.

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel" rendered="#{YOUR_CONDITION}" columns="1">
        <h:panelGroup>           
         <th class="header"><h:outputText value="#{supplierScorecard.treeItemList[1].m1.header}" /> </th>
      </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

If you want to hide it by javascript, wrap the `<th>` tags with a span and dynamicly change visibilty.

```
<span id="panel">  
    <th class="header"><h:outputText value="#{supplierScorecard.treeItemList[1].m1.header}" /> </th>
</span>

document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: hi what does namespace p stands for?

Comment: It's from PrimeFaces. Erencan somehow incorrectly assumed that you were using PrimeFaces, even though you have stated that *nowhere* in your current question nor previously asked ones.

Comment: I have confused about PrimeFases. I have updated my post. Thanks for correcting me @BalusC. I will be more careful.